# A beginners questions about PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

So I’ve just started on PHP in school and I have got an assignment that says “Make a small news site with styling on the news elements” so I started by making a form which members can post news onto another page with. Well I know how to access the data that has been sent to the database from the user but my question is:

How do you keep making that replicating `css` and `html` for the “news block” that replicates every time a user posts a news block? Do you make a variable in PHP or take the `html` and `css` in the database with the user information ?

Comment: Try adding some code to your question. That should get you some help faster.

Comment: As this is your homework, I don't want to spoil the learning experience for you but a hint would be you need to look at understanding **recursion** and **loops**

Comment: Sounds more like html/css question than PHP to me. You don't have any "replicating" CSS, you just write your css in a .css file and include that file in html <head>.

Comment: If by "replicating CSS", you mean adding inline `style` attributes, don't.  Add your CSS to a CSS file, and then just add classes to the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `foreach` for that.

Here is some info:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

so after you performed your query to get your data out of the data base
you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row.['article']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Now you create a table row for each new article. The way you formulated your question, this is what you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks i think that'll do it ^^

Comment: Then accept this as an aswer and let's move on...

Comment: half a plus for the answer, half a plus for the name. +1 total.